# How to change the language of my application programmatically for the largest number of versions

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an API from where I obtain data according to the language button that the user selects, what I require is to be able to achieve that when selecting the option and loading the corresponding data, all the texts of the app are also changed from the code, I already have the XML of each language created. Thanks in advance. I have used a code but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

[image: Select Language from Espanol, English, Portugues]

```
private static void setApplicationLocale(String locale) {

        Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            config.setLocale(new Locale(locale.toLowerCase()));
        } else {
            config.locale = new Locale(locale.toLowerCase());
        }
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
    }
```